# C - Passing a message_t parameter

Tags: c, pointers, parameters

Ok so I have this code and was wondering if anybody could confirm that I have the pointers (* and &) in the right places. Heres the general jist of it

```
int main() {
  message_t msg; //this is a structure
  write(&msg);
}

write(message_t *msg) {
  putBuffer(msg);
}
```

I really am confused by this pointer business, way too used to working in java.
Thanks!

Comment: Does `putBuffer` modify the contents of the variable passed in? Or does it really take a `const message_t *` instead?

Comment: putBuffer puts (msg) onto a buffer so no
but I have another function similar to this that does change msg

Comment: @RockJake28 Then why would it change at all, anywhere?

Comment: Looks ok to me. If you need a quick overview of pointers, this would be a good reference: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/

Comment: @H2CO3 Lets say putBuffer does modify msg...is the syntax correct for the original msg in main to be changed by the write function?

Comment: @RockJake28 If `putBuffer` modifies the object pointed to by `msg`, then it's OK. If you want to modify the `msg` pointer *itself,* then you have to use another level of indirection, since everything is passed by value in C.

Comment: For what it's worth, it might help to visualize pointers with the house analogy. The address of a variable (called the left hand value) is analogous to the address of a house. The value of a variable (called the right hand value) is analogous to who lives in the house. With a pointer, the value of the pointer is the address of another variable of the same type. Dereferencing the pointer shows the contents (value) of the address it is pointing to. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that works, as long as you have the prototype to the write function somewhere about int main().

About your confusion with pointers, these tutorials [here](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=16) will help you. He gets into pointers and references at tutorial 38. I learned about how pointers and stuff works through these tutorials, I would suggest them they'll help clear things up. The tutorials may be about c++, but most of the stuff he goes through will work just as fine in C, and anything that doesn't should be easy to get working in C.